# Make columns in my table to be only as wide as the text of the longest text element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to change my table's width from 33.33% width to auto but whenever I do that it breaks. I want each column in my table to be only as wide as the text of the longest text element.

```js
new PerfectScrollbar('#table tbody');
```

```css
     #table thead {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
      }

      #table tbody {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
      }

      #table tr {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
      }

      #table tbody {
        max-height: 370px;
        overflow-y: auto;
        overflow-x:hidden;
        position: relative;
      }

      #table thead th {
        background: #406AA3;
        color: white;
      }

      #table tbody td {
        display: block;
        width: 33.33%;
        float: left;
        height: 41px;
      }

      #table thead th {
        display: block;
        width: 33.33%;
        float: left;
        border: 1px solid #dee2e6;
        height: 41px;
      }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/utatti/perfect-scrollbar/master/css/perfect-scrollbar.css">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/utatti/perfect-scrollbar/master/dist/perfect-scrollbar.js"></script>

<div class="row pt-2">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div>
          <table class="table table-bordered" id="table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th><th>Age</th><th>Occupation</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Alex</td><td>20</td><td>Student</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Paul</td><td>23</td><td>Engineer</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Chris</td><td>19</td><td>Human being</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Satoshi</td><td>30</td><td>Pokemon trainer</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Jun</td><td>27</td><td>Hero</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Yong</td><td>27</td><td>Money maker</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Alex</td><td>20</td><td>Student</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Paul</td><td>23</td><td>Engineer</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Chris</td><td>19</td><td>Human being</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Satoshi</td><td>30</td><td>Pokemon trainer</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Jun</td><td>27</td><td>Hero</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Yong</td><td>27</td><td>Money maker</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: jfiddle is broken

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO https://jsfiddle.net/r2tnx9qz/11/

Comment: @sbattoh. Can you provide us with html and css you've done so far

Comment: @staskrak check out my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/r2tnx9qz/11/

Comment: @sbattoh now it looks much better

Comment: yea thank you! any ideas on how to solve my issue? @staskrak

Comment: if you're going to use tables, don't touch their display property that defies the purpose, also think about using flexbox instead.

Comment: I had to change the tables display property in order to get the perfectscrollbar plugin working unfortunately. Do you have a working demo using flexbox? @ZohirSalak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) plugin and it solved all kinds of issues that I was having.

Answer (score 1):

Since flebox goes either vertically or horizontally, I don't think `flexbox` is a good fit, because we want the columns to care for their content, but instead we can use [`CSS Grid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) which is basically flexbox only it care for both vertical and horizontal.

```js
new PerfectScrollbar('.scroll');
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.scroll {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  max-height: 150px;
  position: relative;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
}

.headercell {
  padding: 10px;
  background: dodgerblue;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.tablecell {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/utatti/perfect-scrollbar/master/css/perfect-scrollbar.css">
<div class="scroll">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="headercell">Name</div>
    <div class="headercell">Long Column Header Age</div>
    <div class="headercell">Occupation</div>

    <div class="tablecell">Alex</div>
    <div class="tablecell">20</div>
    <div class="tablecell">Student</div>

    <div class="tablecell ">Chris</div>
    <div class="tablecell">20</div>
    <div class="tablecell">Human Being</div>

    <div class="tablecell ">Satoshi</div>
    <div class="tablecell">20</div>
    <div class="tablecell">Pokemon Trainer</div>

    <div class="tablecell ">Yong</div>
    <div class="tablecell">20</div>
    <div class="tablecell">Engineer</div>

    <div class="tablecell ">Long First Name...</div>
    <div class="tablecell">20</div>
    <div class="tablecell">Engineer</div>

    <div class="tablecell ">Name</div>
    <div class="tablecell">20</div>
    <div class="tablecell">A Really Long Occupation</div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://rawgit.com/utatti/perfect-scrollbar/master/dist/perfect-scrollbar.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I created the table using css display property.

```css
.tableCell {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid #dee2e6;
  height: 41px;
}

.tableRow {
  display: table-row;
}

.table {
  display: table;
  width: 200px
}

.tableBody {
  display: table-row-group;
}

.tableHeading {
  display: table-header-group;
}

.tableHead {
  display: table-cell;
  background: #406AA3;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid #dee2e6;
  height: 41px;
}

.container {
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 100px
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="table">
    <div class="tableHeading">
      <div class="tableRow">
        <div class="tableHead">Name</div>
        <div class="tableHead">Age</div>
        <div class="tableHead">Occupation</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tableBody">
      <div class="tableRow">
        <div class="tableCell ">Alex</div>
        <div class="tableCell">20</div>
        <div class="tableCell">Student</div>
      </div>
      <div class="tableRow">
        <div class="tableCell ">CHris</div>
        <div class="tableCell">20</div>
        <div class="tableCell">Human Being</div>
      </div>
      <div class="tableRow">
        <div class="tableCell ">Satoshi</div>
        <div class="tableCell">20</div>
        <div class="tableCell">Pokemon Trainer</div>
      </div>
      <div class="tableRow">
        <div class="tableCell ">Yong</div>
        <div class="tableCell">20</div>
        <div class="tableCell">Engineer</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that's exactly what I want but the scrollbar plugin I had doesn't work in your example

Comment: Is it just me or is this answer super underrated? There are a lot of annoying things about table elements in terms of styling and this seems to be a solution that addresses all of them?